# Install mysql-server 5.7 on Redhat with a custom username and password

Tags: mysql, shell, redhat

I want to install a mysql-server 5.7 on Redhat with a custom username and password in a shell script.

For Ubuntu, I see a 3 line command as follows, I want same kind of approach for Redhat in a simple way

```
echo "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" | debconf-set-selections
echo "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" | debconf-set-selections
apt -y install mysql-server
```

**Update 1:-**

```
    newPassword=root

    echo "Stopping mysql..."
    systemctl stop mysqld

    echo "Setting the mySQL environment option.." 
    systemctl set-environment MYSQLD_OPTS="--skip-grant-tables"

    echo "Starting mysql ignoring password verification.."
    systemctl start mysqld

    echo "Updating the root user password with your provided password"
    echo "UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('$newPassword') WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';" | mysql -u root
    echo "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;" | mysql -u root

    echo "Stopping mysql.."
    systemctl stop mysqld

    echo "Un setting the mySQL environment option so it starts normally next time.."
    systemctl unset-environment MYSQLD_OPTS

    echo "Start mysql normally.."
    systemctl start mysqld
```

I have tried the above answer. It works well. But after logged into to mysql with updated password. I see the following error

```
 mysql -uroot -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 5
Server version: 5.7.21

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases;
ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.
mysql> exit
```

Kindly let me know how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

In Redhat, first create user account for MySQL. For example `user:mysql` and `password:blablabla` and default login `path:/app/mysql/`. Once done login as mysql user and set necessary setting in .bash_profile and finally install the MySQL.

Hope this will help you.